# Run nginx.exe on Windows as another user

Tags: nginx, ansible

I'm working on a project for deploying pentest lab with terraform & ansible. All is working good except that last problem.

In my lab I have a nginx server running on a Windows server. Nginx with php works when I start them as Administrator with ansible but i need them to run with a non admin local account.

For the php i've made a wrapper using this tools : https://github.com/antonioCoco/RunasCs

But it doesn't work with nginx cause of a working directory problem :

Here is the error :

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> .\RunAsCs.exe nginx ***** C:\Web\nginx-1.19.6\nginx.exe
[*] Warning: GetUserProfileDirectory failed with error code: 2
[*] Warning: Unable to obtain environment for user 'nginx'.
[*] Warning: Environment of created process might be incorrect.
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: CreateFile() "logs/error.log" failed (3: The system cannot find the path specified)
2021/03/06 10:18:33 [emerg] 5556#6124: CreateFile() "C:\Windows\system32/conf/nginx.conf" failed (3: The system cannot find the path specified)
```

And that's normal because as you can see my wrapper start in Windows/System32

I would like to know if there is a solution either with nginx.conf or with ansible to start this exe as the "nginx" user.

This is a working code for starting nginx as Administrator

```
- name: Starting web server
      win_shell: .\nginx.exe
      args:
        chdir: C:\Web\nginx-1.19.6
      async: 180
      poll: 0
```

I know that there is a psexec module in ansible but psexec will work only for Local Admin account and the goal of that is that my nginx don't run as Local Admin.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Dumb question - when the `nginx` user was created in ansible it was 'test logged in with' to create the profile directory? The error indicates that the user's profile directory does not exist

Comment: Hello, 
No that's not an error that's just a warning. If i run whoami with the same exe I got the same warning but whoami execute just fine.